# Почему результат Graphics.FillPath(path) отличается от Graphics.DrawPolygon(Pens.Black, path.PathPoints)

Tags: c#, graphics

Всем привет мне нужно преобразовть текст в коллекцию точек. Использую для этого `GraphicsPath` но не получается ожидаемый результат.

```
GraphicsPath myPath = new GraphicsPath();

// Set up all the string parameters.
string stringText = "Sample Text";
System.Drawing.FontFamily family = new System.Drawing.FontFamily("Arial");

int fontStyle = (int)System.Drawing.FontStyle.Italic;
int emSize = 26;

System.Drawing.Point origin = new System.Drawing.Point(100, 100);
StringFormat format = StringFormat.GenericTypographic;

// Add the string to the path.
myPath.AddString(stringText,
    family,
    fontStyle,
    emSize,
    origin,
    format);

//sample 1
Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(480, 480);
using (var gr = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap))
{
    gr.Clear(System.Drawing.Color.White);
    gr.FillPath(System.Drawing.Brushes.Red, myPath);
}

bitmap.Save(@"D:\test.bmp");

//sample 2
Bitmap bitmap1 = new Bitmap(480, 480);
using (var gr = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap1))
{
    gr.Clear(System.Drawing.Color.White);
    gr.DrawPolygon(Pens.Black, myPath.PathPoints);
}

bitmap1.Save(@"D:\test1.bmp");
```

на выходе в первом случае все как часы, а во втором результат немного другой.

**Как можно получить правильную коллекцию точек используя `PathPoints`?**

Под *правильной* я имею в виду без эффекта, как будто, не отрывая ручки написан текст.

Пример 1

[image: Пример 1]

Пример 2

[image: Пример 2]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DrawPolygon отрисовывает многогранник по точкам. Точки у вас неприрыны, от сюда и появляется эффект "как будто, не отрываю ручки написан текст".

Как решение - разделить каждую букву текста на отдельные массивы. Сделать это можно примерно так:

```
string stringText = "Sample Text";
System.Drawing.FontFamily family = new System.Drawing.FontFamily("Arial");

int fontStyle = (int)System.Drawing.FontStyle.Italic;
int emSize = 26;

System.Drawing.Point origin = new System.Drawing.Point(100, 100);
StringFormat format = StringFormat.GenericTypographic;

var myPaths = new List<GraphicsPath>();

foreach (var symbol in stringText)
{
    var gp = new GraphicsPath();
    gp.AddString(symbol.ToString(),
        family,
        fontStyle,
        emSize,
        origin,
        format);

    myPaths.Add(gp);
}

//sample 1
Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(480, 480);
foreach (var myPath in myPaths)
{
    using (var gr = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap))
    {
        gr.Clear(System.Drawing.Color.White);
        gr.FillPath(System.Drawing.Brushes.Red, myPath);
    }
}

bitmap.Save(@"D:\test.bmp");

//sample 2
Bitmap bitmap1 = new Bitmap(480, 480);

foreach (var myPath in myPaths)
{
    using (var gr = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap1))
    {
        gr.Clear(System.Drawing.Color.White);
        gr.DrawPolygon(Pens.Black, myPath.PathPoints);
    }
}

bitmap1.Save(@"D:\test1.bmp");
```